# Specifying a custom mount point for an empty partition

Tags: mount, mountpoint

I have ubuntu 12.04 running on my system. I repartitioned my hard disk yesterday, I have an empty 40GiB partiton.

Can I mount it at say `/data-part` ? How do I do this ?

I have formatted it as `ext4`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**=== EDIT STARTS ===**

I am assuming you want it to be mounted every time you boot, if what you want is to mount it one time:

```
$ sudo mkdir /data-part
$ sudo mount /dev/sdaX /data-part
```

should do the trick.

**=== EDIT ENDS ===**

Sure you can. First you need to know device file of the partition you need to mount (it should be something like sda* in most cases). If you don't know, install and run gparted and find out device file of the partition.

[image: gparted]

Once you find the device file, fire up your favorite editor from terminal (assuming device file you want to mount is /dev/sdaX, replace accordingly):

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

When editor opens, go to the bottom of the file and add a line like:

```
/dev/sdaX /data-part ext4 defaults 0 0
```

And then, all you need to do is to create a directory at mount point:

```
$ sudo mkdir /data-part
```

After your next reboot, partition should be mounted at the mount point automatically.

Comment: Awesome, This will be first thing I'll do once I get back home..
Yes I want it to be mouted automatically everytime... So this is how partitions are handled in Linux ?? Is this like Windows' D:/, E:/ etc.,

Comment: Yes, you can mount a partition to directory you want. What I can suggest is that, instead of mounting partitions in random places, you shall keep mounted directories in a specific folder. For example, I am keeping them in /media folder (like /media/storage /media/backup).

Answer (score 1):

Try running these commands:

```
sudo mkdir -p /data-part
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb1 /data-part
```

This will do the trick.