# Non existing Mount Points fails to automount on boot, How to fix this?

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, filesystem, mountpoint

I think I've messed up something with my partition mount points.

---

OK, this is the thing. When I have been fresh installing Ubuntu 12.10 from a Live CD, I made all my partitions with **ext4** file system format and mounted them at random mount points (now special interest on `/DOS` and `/Windows`, [see it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5euf.png)). After installation complete, I wasn't happy without seeing my partitions appear as shown in a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oqW7.png) at the red "A". As I had them there on my previous older laptop, witch was dual boot alongside with WimXP, and these partitions were **NTFS**. So I decided to format them back to **NTFS**. I've labeled these **HDD1** and And **HDD2**. And somehow it become mounted an the directory `/mnt/33E6E20A00342E2D` and `/mt/486FFA615D0979A2` seen in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oqW7.png) at "B" and "C" marks. Despites all that, in general it worked all fine. Until I boot the machine next time, I encountered with the problem explaned here: "[How to avoid "S to skip" message on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120/how-do-i-avoid-the-s-to-skip-message-on-boot)". I did try all the mentioned solutions and none worked in my case. As in my case there in no longer any partition as `/DOS` and `/Windows`.
Now from here: "[Specifying a custom mount point for an empty partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248563/specifying-a-custom-mount-point-for-an-empty-partition)", I found that it may be the better way of having my partitions in a place "[A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oqW7.png)" in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oqW7.png). I am willing to reformat these partitions back again to **ext4**, and mount them in a folder as `/example/HDD1` and `/example/HDD2` so I easy and quick access when needed. But I get now very *confused* what to do next.

Should I use [Disks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ob6h4.png) or [GParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWdfS.png)? And what should I do with my "S to skip"? I can't just delete [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTuRM.png) directories.

---

### Bonus:

! [Picture with "A,B,C"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oqW7.png)
! [Picture with 2 Folders Selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5euf.png) (Containing a total of 0 items)
! [Picture with Disks-sda1 selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ob6h4.png) (HDD1, `/windows` before)
! [Picture with Disks-sda5 selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4A4H.png) (HDD2, `/dos` before)
! [Picture with GParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWdfS.png)
! [Can't delete folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTuRM.png) (directory with 0 items)

---

## Edit 1

I have just deleted the directories using **Nautilus** as *root*. Here is the process outcome:

```
gedis@gedis-A8J:~$ sudo su 
[sudo] password for gedis: 
root@gedis-A8J:/home/gedis# nautilus 
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory 
Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing. 


** (nautilus:24006): WARNING **: Could not inhibit power management: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Name "org.gnome.SessionManager" does not exist 

** (nautilus:24006): WARNING **: Could not inhibit power management: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Name "org.gnome.SessionManager" does not exist 
root@gedis-A8J:/home/gedis# exit 
exit 
/bin/rm: cannot remove `/run/user/root/gvfs': Is a directory 
gedis@gedis-A8J:~$
```

After rebooting the problem "press S to skip" is still here.
Will try now updating the **Grub2**

---

## Edit 2

Just updated the **Grub2**. This is the process outcome:

```
gedis@gedis-A8J:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for gedis: 
root@gedis-A8J:/home/gedis# gksu update-grub
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-34-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-34-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
root@gedis-A8J:/home/gedis# exit
exit
gedis@gedis-A8J:~$ exit
```

After rebooting the problem "press S to skip" is still here...

### How can I fix this?

Comment: You may need to be root before you delete Windows. launch nautilus (the file Manager) wuth `sudo nautilus` from terminal.

Comment: Just a little thing more, if I just delete the folder `/dos` and `/windows` will solve all my "press S to skip" problem while booting?

Comment: The Grub programme looks for a boot loader, so you need to find the windows boot partition, and delete that. I believe it's about 50Mb in size. This will stop Grub from seeing the Windows installation. The other way is to download Grub Customizer from the Programme Manager and have a play :)

Comment: The thing is that i **don't** have any windows installed at all... It's just that the partition have been previously mounted at the point named *windows*. Before installing Ubuntu 12.10, all the partitions have been formated (set zeros).

Comment: @SimplySimon Can I just update Grub via Terminal after delete these directories (`/dos` & `/windows`)? Will this work, or is there any other mayor issue I could be heading towards?

Comment: Grub is easily broken. by all means follow some instructions, but be very careful.

Comment: @SimplySimon I made both steps (remove the directories as `root` and update the Grub2), as seen in a question updates. But the issue is still here... **What can I do now?**

Comment: Have you edited your `/etc/fstab`? If not, simply remove the unnecessary entries.

Comment: @meskobalazs, It worked, I just added **"#"** at the beginning of these lines where the _Mount Point_ was mentioned as `/dos` and `/window`. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link shows how to edit `fstab`. You have the entries (`/dos` and `/windows`) in `fstab` and that is why it is trying to mount those entries on reboot.

Check `fstab` and make sure you specify the same format in the `fstab` entry as partition is formatted. If not running *Windows* better to use **ext4**, but to use partition you will also need to set ownership & permissions to easily use partition as a data partition.

**Anytime you edit `fstab`, run this command to make sure all entries are valid. It will remount and give no errors if correct:**

> sudo mount -a

Comment: As I understood, when editing `/etc/fstab` with **Gedit** I can just add **"#"** at the beginning of these  lines were the _Mount Point_ is `/dos` and `/windows` (as the directories as such do not exist anyway)?

Answer (score 2):

If you download Grub Customizer from the Software Centre, when you run the programme, you can edit the following on the General Settings tab.:

[image: Grub Customizer]

- Un-check the look for other operating systems.
- Set the Timeout to 0 Seconds